# X is a cauchy sequence show | X | is a cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

X is a cauchy sequence implies that |xn-xm|<ε for n,m>N

I've tried breaking this up into the different case for xn, xm greater than or equall to zero, but I am struggling with when xn and xm have different signs.

The best thing I could come up with was that if X is cauchy sequence the only time two consecutive members in the sequence will have alternative signs is if it converges to zero but I'm not sure how to use this?

Comment: Hint: reverse triangle inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the *reverse triangle inequality*, which states
$$\bigl| |a|-|b|\bigr| \leq |a-b|$$
For a quick proof using the triangle inequality, we have that 
\begin{align}
|a| & = |a+b-b| \\
& \leq |a-b|+|b|
\end{align}
so $|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$. Symmetry gives us the other inequality $|b|-|a| \leq |a-b|$, so $\bigl| |a|-|b|\bigr| \leq |a-b|$.

Then 
$$\bigl||x_n|-|x_m|\bigr| \leq |x_n-x_m| <\epsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

You lose a *ton* of meaning when you leave out quantifiers. Don't do that.

A sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy if : **for every** $\epsilon > 0$ **there exists** $N \in \mathbb N$ with the property that **for every** $n,m \in \mathbb N$,  $n,m \ge N$ implies $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$.

Anyway, use the fact that $\big||x_n| - |x_m|\big| \le |x_n - x_m|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ be Cauchy. We prove that $(|x_n|)$ is Cauchy also.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $m$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $m \geq N$ and $n \geq N$, then $|x_n - x_m| < \varepsilon$. Let $m$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $m \geq N$ and $n \geq N$, then by the alternative form of the triangle inequality (also called the *reverse triangle inequality*), we have
$$
\bigl| |x_n| - |x_m| \bigr| \leq |x_n - x_m| < \varepsilon.
$$
Thus, $(|x_n|)$ is Cauchy.